# Difference between \skipeval and \dimeval

Tags: lengths, dimensions, glue, dimension-expressions

What is the difference between `\skipeval` and `\dimeval`? They appear to produce the same result, but perhaps `\dimeval` removes the glue?

```
\rule{\dimeval{ \linewidth plus 1cm minus 1cm - 1cm}}{1pt} a\\
\rule{\skipeval{\linewidth plus 1cm minus 1cm - 1cm}}{1pt} a\\
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are thin wrappers around the eTeX primitives `\dimexpr` and `\glueexpr`

In a dimen context such as a rule length both may be used but compare a skip/glue context such as setting `\baselineskip`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\baselineskip{\skipeval{20pt plus 2pt - 3pt}}
\showthe\baselineskip

\setlength\baselineskip{\dimeval{20pt plus 2pt - 3pt}}
\showthe\baselineskip

\end{document}
```

shows `\skipeval` producing `17.0pt plus 2.0pt`  but `\dimeval` produces `20.0pt plus 2.0pt` and -3pt gets typeset. Actually the \dimeval is terminated by the `p` of `plus` but `\setlength` then absorbs the `plus 2pt` as a primitive skip component, leaving -3pt as trailing tokens that are typset as text

Comment: Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 3):

`\rule` is not the best tool for comparing `\dimen`s with `\skip`'s, because the `plus` or `minus` specifications are ignored.

The definition of `\rule` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\rule{\@ifnextchar[\@rule{\@rule[\z@]}}%
 \def\@rule[#1]#2#3{%
   \leavevmode
   \hbox{%
     \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%
     \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
     \setlength\@tempdimc{#3}%
     \advance\@tempdimc\@tempdima
     \vrule\@width\@tempdimb\@height\@tempdimc\@depth-\@tempdima}}
```

The token `\@width` stands for `width`; since `\vrule` requires a `\dimen` either explicit or with a register, in the latter cases it coerces a `\skip` to a `\dimen`.

So the fact that `\rule{123pt plus 12pt minus 42pt}{1pt}` works without error is just a consequence of the implementation and the resulting width would be 123pt anyway.

It's better to compare the values you get. Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\mytest}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\mytest}{\dimeval{\linewidth plus 100pt minus 100pt - 100pt}}

\texttt{\the\mytest}

\setlength{\mytest}{\skipeval{\linewidth plus 100pt minus 100pt - 100pt}}

\texttt{\the\mytest}

\end{document}
```

where I changed `1cm` into `100pt` in order not to get decimals.

[image]

What's that “-100pt” doing at the top? That's the proof your attempts are *not* equivalent.

Indeed, your

```
\dimeval{\linewidth plus 100pt minus 100pt - 100pt}
```

returns 345.0pt, because `p` is extraneous to `\dimexpr` (on which `\dimeval` is based) so in the end LaTeX does

```
\setlength{\mytest}{345.0pt plus 100pt minus 100pt - 100pt}
```

which becomes

```
\mytest=345.0pt plus 100pt minus 100pt - 100pt\relax
```

(because of the implementation of `\setlength`). The part

```
\mytest=345.0pt plus 100pt minus 100pt
```

is a complete `\skip` specification; then TeX typesets `-100pt`.

To the contrary, the argument in `\skipeval` is valid for `\glueexpr` and the length is computed as expected.

Can the wrong input to `\dimeval` be caught? I don't think it's possible without performing assignments, which would make the command unexpandable.

Comment: Very helpful answer!